# Best Practise to use a CustomControl with ContentProperty also as BasedOn Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a `Control` - `HtSideBarItem` with a `ContentProperty`. Now in 80% of the cases, I set a `CustomButton` as `Content`. Now I would like to create a second class `HtSideBarButton` which inherits the default `style` and set a default content.

#### HtSideBarItem (Trimmed)

```
[ContentProperty("Content")]
public class HtSideBarItem : Control
{
    public DataTemplate ContentTemplate
    {
        get => (DataTemplate) GetValue(ContentTemplateProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentTemplateProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(HtSideBarItem));

    public object Content
    {
        get => GetValue(ContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(object), typeof(HtSideBarItem));
}


<Style TargetType="sideBar:HtSideBarItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="sideBar:HtSideBarItem">
                <Grid>
                    <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

#### XAML HtSideBarButton

```
<Style TargetType="sideBar:HtSideBarButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type sideBar:HtSideBarItem}}">        
    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <controls:CustomButton
                    Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=sideBar:HtSideBarButton}, Path=Height}" 
                    Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=sideBar:HtSideBarButton}, Path=Text}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now this works as expected, with one problem. I would like to have `designTime` data. But this is not possible because of the `DataTemplate`. So is there a better way to have "a base style" and inherit and just change the content with the ability of `designTime` data?

Comment: A Control with Content and ContentTemplate. How is it different from ContentControl?

Comment: There are more (around 10) `DependencyProperties`, I left these out for clarity.

Comment: You could still derive from ContentControl...

Comment: You're right, overseen that.. but this won't solve my problem anyway.